# I can't delete container and objects by object storage swift

Tags: storage, openstack-swift

When I delete a container by swift, the following error occurrs.

> $ swift -A http://192.168.1.120:8010/auth/v1.0 -U
> test:vo8AlYgTxchsh37YF1mm -K cqAIBc9B3mIGvJt5DbDmkG3j6Vi0OaEa delete -a
>
> ・・・
>
> Error Deleting: test: Container DELETE failed: http://192.168.1.120:8010/v1/AUTH_test/test 409 Conflict  [first 60
> chars of response] <html><h1>Conflict</h1><p>There was a conflict when
> trying t

The environment is as follows.

Storage is Object storage swift. (QNAP application)

CentOS7(Client side)

yum update

yum install python-setuptools

yum install epel-release

yum install python-pip --enablerepo=epel

pip install python-swiftclient

I would appreciate it if you could give me advice.

Comment: Are you able to upload objects? If so, can you show your account/user conf for this user? (Password is not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete a container without deleting the objects inside them.If that's not the case more probable that there are multiple objects/containers with the same name.